# Redux Toolkit generate and return an id (return data from action)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create an object and add it to a reducer, but have the action/reducer take care of generating the id.

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61921025/1164573), it seems the accepted pattern is to generate the id in the action creator:

```js
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addTodo: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        state.push(action.payload);
      },
      prepare(text) {
        const id = uuid();
        return { payload: {text, id} };
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**However, suppose I want to then use / refer to the id after creating the todo, something like**

```
dispatch(addTodo('Say hello world')) // creates a todo with a uuid
...
id = <some way to get the id>
doSomethingElseWithTodoGivenId()
```

Does Redux-Toolkit provide any assistance with achieving this? I looked at [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), but that appears to be more focussed around async data fetching status.

I know I can do this with redux-thunk (by awaiting the dispatch and having the thunk action generate the id):

```js
const id = await dispatch(createTodoWithGeneratedId('Say hello world'))
```

or by having the caller generate the id. But I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfourtonately, `dispatch` is not working that way. Plain Redux `dispatch` call [retuns a dispatched action](https://redux.js.org/api/store#returns-1), but `redux-toolkit` using `thunk` middleware by default that changes a `dispatch` returning value to promise that fullfiled with dispatched action. You can't get a result of dispatching result from `dispatch` call itself, it is impossible and conflicts with it's nature.

However, you can create a thunk that dispatches different actions based on promise result. Check official documentation about [creating thunk with side effects](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#async-logic-and-side-effects). For more advanced usage check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073808/13781208) in SO.

If you are using `redux-toolkit`, you can use [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), it is implements the same logic but without much more boilerplate code.

Comment: imo this reality is where RTK fails to me.. i originally liked handling api requests through thunk side effects, which added consistency to response middlewares (like handling authorization errors) but sometimes i want to make api requests and return those values to the component state... now i have to write a separate controller to handle those network request errors

Answer (score 0):

There is no accepted pattern in this case. Sometimes you have to figure out things based on your needs. That is why leetcode algorithms are such a big deal in hiring process.

If you follow your above implementation

```
  import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

  prepare(text) {
    const id = nanoid();
    return { payload: {text, id} };
  }
```

the only way to get the "id" is you have to get the state with the `useSelector` and then loop through where `text===currentToDo`. This is too much work for a simple task.

Instead, why not pass id with the dispatching? You arrange your payload where accepts an object. (Because you cannot pass multiple args)

```
const id=nanoid()
dispatch(addTodo({todo:'Say hello world',id:id}))
// now use that id todo something
```

in this scenario, you do not even need the `prepare` phase. (you did not before neither). just push the payload object to the array